# 2 colums div with the same auto height

Tags: css, html

I'm doing a layout for an online shop. I wanna have a two-column layout, with the two div at the same height, but not for all the divs, but only the two on the same row.
the problem is, that the pictures do not all have the same height, so sometimes the left div is higher which makes the next div come on the right side (`float: left`).
Is there any way to solved it without the same height for all divs?

HTML:

```
<div id="inhalt">
  <div class="listext">Title<br /><br />
    <div><span class="listebild">picture</span>text</div>
    <div class="listepreis">price</div>
    <div class="listemenge">formular stuff</div>
  </div>

  <div class="listext">Title<br /><br />
    <div><span class="listebild">picture</span>text</div>
    <div class="listepreis">price</div>
    <div class="listemenge">formular stuff</div>
  </div>

  <div class="listext">Title<br /><br />
    <div><span class="listebild">picture</span>text</div>
    <div class="listepreis">price</div>
    <div class="listemenge">formular stuff</div>
  </div>

CSS:
#inhalt
  {
 width: 600px;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 1px;
 margin-left: 1px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 padding: 10px 10px 20px;
 background-image: url(http://www.kostuemkaiser.ch/images/bg_3.png);
 border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
 }  `
.listebild {
    width: 68px;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom:25px;
 }


 .listext {width: 300px;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    min-height:170px;
 }

 .listepreis {
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-right:15px;
    font-size:12px;
 }

 .listemenge {
    float: left;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top: 17px;
 }
```

Is there a way to make the height smaller if the pictures of both divs on the same row is small? I do need this "single div" style, because the data will be filled in automaticaly.
This is how it looks with `min-height 170px`: [the problem](http://www.cedricgschwind.com/kkss_1) if I take it away, sometimes the left div squeezes in at the right side...
Thanx for ideas

Comment: It took me some time to get what you wanted: if you want the fragments to be aligned - you should probably either set the height of it or limit the sizes of the elements inside it (so that eventually the width/height would be the same). if you want a two column layout - just use the answer i provided. good luck

Comment: Thyx and sorry for the bad explanation...
That's the way i'm doing it now, i just hoped i could leave the content size unlimited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inline-block` instead of floating and your problem should go away. Change your `.listext` class to the following:

```
.listext {
    width: 298px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom:25px;
 }
```

Note that we had to take a few pixels off the width in order for `inline-block` to work. I've also removed the min-height as it is no longer necessary.

For more information on `inline-block`, I'd suggest reading [this article](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/).

Comment: Thank you, that comes very close to what I need. But still the boxes have strange margins between themselves: http://www.cedricgschwind.com/kkss/screen.jpg

Comment: Try adding `vertical-align: top;` to the `.listext` class too and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I gather that you want the left and right bit to be aligned, however i couldn't get that from your question and layout so instead i've made you a POC which shows you how using

```
display: table;
```

and

```
display: table-cell;
```

can solve your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/B2k2a/1/